# "Invalid argument" on posted array foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Yo, so I have this simple foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['carID'] as $carID) 
{  
    $query = "DELETE FROM cars WHERE carIndex = ".$carID."";
    echo $query;
}
```

but I'm getting error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in K:\XAMPP\htdocs\Cars\deletecar.php on line 8

Line 8 being:

```
foreach ($_POST['carID'] as $carID)
```

The array "($_POST['carID']" is created from multiple checkboxes on another page and posted just using a submit button form.

The form is:

```
<form name="input" action="delete.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <while loop>
    <input type="checkbox" name="carID[]" value="'.$row['carIndex'].'">
    <end loop>
</form>
```

The actual check box is within a loop based on mysql query.

The array made here is sent to a page which displays the selected database records using a foreach loop to create the WHERE statment for the query. The exact same foreach which is now not working.

I do:

```
$where = " WHERE ";    
foreach ($_POST['carID'] as $carID) 
{  
    $where = $where." carIndex = ".$carID." OR";
}
$where = substr($where, 0, -3);
```

and this works perfectly fine.

I then have a are you sure you wanna delete Yes and No buttons.

The yes button I have tried as just a normal submit button as so:

```
    <form name="input" action="deletecar.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Yes" value="'.$_POST['carID'].'">
    </form>
```

But on submission, on the deletecar.php page I get the error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in K:\XAMPP\htdocs\Cars\deletecar.php on line 8

The full code for deletecar.php is:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cdb')
      or die('Error connecting');

echo $_POST['carID'];

foreach ($_POST['carID'] as $carID) 
{  
    $query = "DELETE FROM cars WHERE carIndex = ".$carID."";
    echo $query;
} 

//header ("Location: profile.php?username=".$_SESSION['username']."")

?>
```

The top echo for the posted data echos out "Array" so as far as I can tell it is getting the data as it knows it is an array. Then theres the disabled redirect.

It probably something simple, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: print_r($_POST['carID']) and show your result i think you need to change  <input type="checkbox" name="carID[]" value="<?php echo $row['carIndex']?>">

Comment: @RakeshSharma I placed print_r($_POST['carID']) in deletecar.php and it just displayed "array" like with the echo. I just don't understand how it can be fine doing the foreach in one file but not another.

Comment: Missing quotes in `WHERE carIndex = ".$carID."";` do `WHERE carIndex = '".$carID."'";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah yeah ty, fixed that, still getting the foreach Invalid Argument error.

Comment: It is possible that none of your checkbox is checked and hence you won't get any result for the same field and hence no array will get passed for the same field.

Comment: @Dikesh There is the page with the check boxes, this leads to a page which displays what the user has checked, and gives the yes or No option for if you're sure they wanna delete them.

So the checkbox values are getting through to page2, but when I try to pass the same array to the next page it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First change your form how you sending two values and where you send `$_POST['carID']` values on this form submit try to send your `carID` values in hidden

```
<form name="input" action="deletecar.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="carID" value="<?php echo $_POST['carID']?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Yes">
    </form>
```

you need to first check `print_r($_POST['carID'])` values. For error you need to apply check and need to refine your queries like

```
$postid = $_POST['carID'];
if(is_array($postid) && sizeof($postid) > 0) {
   foreach ($postid as $carID) 
   {  
      $query = "DELETE FROM cars WHERE carIndex = '$carID'"; //use single quote
      echo $query;
   } 
}
else {
  echo 'Something wrong with post values';
}
```

Comment: I get the "Something wrong with post values" result, so the post value isn't an array, though when I echo it it says "array"? :S

Comment: Just altered form as suggested by @Ravinder and I till get the "Something wrong with post values" result.

Comment: you need to check hidden value of your array on yes submit page using debug tool or echo where it being break so need to debug line by line

Comment: Ah the issue is I'm trying to post an existing array in a form I think, so it will always be received on the other end as "array". How can I pass a php array to another file and also redirect the user there. I've done it with js but that was dealing with jquery values not php.

Answer (score 0):

Form element with name `carID` was missing. Include it in the `form`.

**Change**:

```
<form name="input" action="deletecar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Yes" value="'.$_POST['carID'].'">
</form>
```

**To**:

```
<form name="input" action="deletecar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="carID" value="'.$_POST['carID'].'">
    <input type="submit" value="Yes">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah yes I see the issue there and altered it thanks, but I still get the foreach error.